# python os.makedirs not working with fastapi app

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, operating-system, fastapi

I'm having a problem where in my fastapi app, when I run
`os.makdirs(dir, exist_ok=True)` no dirs get created. When I run just this command alone in a new file, it works, but in my fastapi app, it doesn't work.

I have made sure that my file permissions are okay, and that the logic is being accessed in the app itself.

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because I was running this fastapi app in a docker container as part of my docker compose setup (totally forgot lol).

It WAS creating the dirs, but inside the docker container itself. I had to specify a volume for that service in my compose file, so that they could be accessed on the host filesystem

```
volumes:
  - /var/www/log:/var/www/log
```